# Why can I access object property with an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can somebody explain the behaviour of the following code?

```
let obj = {a:1, b:2}
let i = ['a']
console.log(obj[i])
>> 1
```

Why is it that even an array can be used to access a property inside an object? As a side note this only works with an array of length 1. I have tried researching this but there's no documentation as far as I know that explains why this should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Property names are always strings or [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol).

If you pass something which isn't a string or symbol, it gets converted to a string.

The default `toString()` method on an array is roughly:

```
String.prototype.toString = function () { return this.join(","); }
```

So `['a']` gets converted to `'a'`.

> As a side note this only works with an array of length 1.

It works fine with arrays that are longer. You just need a matching value:

```js
const o = {
    "a,b": "Hello"
}
const a = ["a", "b"];
console.log("" + a);
console.log(o[a]);
```

---

And since any object can be converted to a string, and you can customise the `toString` method, you can do really weird things:

```js
const data = {
  "42": "Hello"
}

class Weird {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.x + 40;
    }
}

const w = new Weird(2);
console.log(data[w]);
```

(Note that doing really weird things is usually a stupid idea that makes it hard to debug your own code two weeks later).

Answer (score 0):

`let obj = {a:1, b:2}`

First you declare an object with 2 properties, a and b with values 1 and 2, respectively.

`let i = ['a']`

Then a variable i is declared, with it's value set to a string array with a single element, 'a'.

`console.log(obj[i])`

In this statement, the value of i is resolved to a string because the array only contains one element, as you mentioned. Due to this, 'a' is a valid property  name for obj because all object properties are either strings, and if you pass something such as an array, it's converted to a string.

If you reference the variable `i`containing the array, and it has multiple elements, it cannot resolve to a single property name without you being more explicit such as `obj[i[0]]`. If you only have one value, it'll resolves to that value.

`obj['a']` is a valid property
`obj['a,b']` is not.